# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in RequestsController#create, can't write unknown attribute `request_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an error regarding saving a request for a job on a website I'm making. Basically the user (candidate) will make a request for a job through the job/show.html.erb page, the comment will then display on the show.html.erb page with any other candidates who have also applied for the job. When the user types their name in the text box and submits it I get the error mentioned above. After looking online it seems the problem lies in my realtionships in the Models. Any ideas?

**RequestsController**

```
 class RequestsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authorise
 #set_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def create
      @job = Job.find params[:job_id]
      @request = @job.requests.new(request_params) <- Error highlights this line
      @request.candidate_id = @current_candidate.id       #sets the user_id FK
      @request.save #saves the @comment
                  # object to the comments table
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html{redirect_to @job}
        end         
   end

   private
   def request_params 
   #This is the method ehich whitelists the data fields from the format
       params.require(:request).permit(:content, :job_id, :candidate_id)
   end
  end
```

**Request Model**

```
 class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :job, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :candidates
 end
```

**Candidate Model**

```
 class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_secure_password
 validates_uniqueness_of:can_email

 belongs_to :request

 validates :can_name, presence: true
 validates :can_surname, presence: true
 validates :college, presence: true
 validates :can_email, presence: true
 validates :address, presence: true
 validates :experience, presence: true
 validates :password_digest, presence: true
 validates :college_year, numericality: { only_integer: true }

 end
```

**Job Model**

```
  class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sector

  has_many :requests, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :employer, presence: true
  validates :sector, presence: true
  validates :experience_req, presence: true
  validates :job_info, presence: true
  end
```

Comment: It looks like for your `request_params` you'll need to add `request_id` along with the other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that in your `routes.rb` file you have the following routes defined:

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :requests
end
```

which nests the routes, (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

It is completely unnecessary to pass in `job_id` in, via the `requests` part of the params. i.e. You don't need to include it as an input in your form because the url already passes the param in.

look at your server output the params hitting your 'create` action should look something like this:

```
params = { job_id: 1, request: {content: "hello world", candidate_id: "123"}}
```

in that case you permit the following:

```
 def request_params 
     params.require(:request).permit(:content, :candidate_id)
 end
```

and the first two lines of create will be correct:

```
 @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
 @request = @job.requests.new(request_params)
```

Comment: By the way - I would reccomend you rename your model. request is protected word - Rails gets pretty flaky if you use protected terms
http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words